# Authenticating with ADAL via REST

Tags: adal

I would like to be able to make some API calls to Microsoft Power BI. According to the [overview documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn877544) a token needs to be obtained using ADAL (Active Directory Authorization Library). I was planning to interface with Power BI via a REST interface but I am not sure how I go about authenticating with ADAL using a REST interface (i.e. purely via HTTP). Examples I have found all show authenticating with ADAL directly with an ADAL DLL and server on premises. Nothing over HTTP.

Has anyone performed authentication with ADAL via a REST implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADAL, the first step is to register the application.  There is a sample that covers that topic in the Readme of the PowerBI-Developers-Repo in GitHub  [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples). Once you have an application registration created, ADAL token acquisition is could be different depending on whether you are trying to get an App Only token or token for a User.  This is dependent on the whether in the application registration you gave it App Permissions (service or daemon, full access to the data) or Delegated Permissions (user scoped, the API can only have access to what the current user has permission). The concepts are discussed in some detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios).

So purely using REST Delegated token acquisitions would be hard, as ADAL requires interaction with the user. However, for a good proof of concept, the App-only token is meant for non-interaction. That is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) in the Microsoft Docs for Azure Active Directory. That acquisition would be a simple `POST` like this:

```
POST <https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id={application id from the Application registration}
&client_secret={Application Key from Azure AD registration}
&resource=https%3A%2F%analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api%2F
```

The full detail on that call is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#service-to-service-access-token-request).

For the user token, you could do this:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={Application ID from the registration}
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri={URL encoded redirect from application registration}
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api%2F
&state=12345
```

The problem with this is that it will have interactive login for the user, so not really REST in that case. If you just browsed to that URL in your browser, replacing {tenant} with your tenant name or ID, the redirect will have a URL parameter `access_token` that will be your JWT token. But for a per REST test and learning, I'd suggest trying the App-only token method first. Once you have that just add the Header: `Authorization: bearer access_token` to your REST calls for the API.